# Crystal Report image only if USB stick is plugged into computer

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to have an image appear on the crystal report only if the usb memory stick is plugged into the computer.  I do not want the image to ever save to the report.  I also do not want to stop them from printing if the memory stick is not plugged in.
Everything I have tried seems to save the item to the report.  Is this request even possible?

Thank-you.

Comment: how are you capturing the USB stick events?

Comment: @Siva - Is the USB stick is plugged in, then it gets the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think is that the best way is to set image location formula in your image placeholder to that USB stick location, for example H:\myimage.png... It will for sure work if that location exist or not. A bit advanced is to generate your report from code and to try catch that USB event and to send some kind of flag to your report.. For example: Make a new bool variable in your report. Via c# code, get a status of your USB stick and send it to the Crystal Report. Here is the pseudo code...

```
c#
var usbStatus = GetUSBStatus();
CrystalReport myCR = new Crystal Report();
myCR["myCRvariable"] = (bool) usbStatus;

Crystal Report
IF(myCRvariable==true)
THEN (...H:\myimage.png)
ELSE
()
```

This way of thinking is for sure leading you in the right direction.

Comment: I can only limp by with crystal reports.  With that being said, is a bool variable and where can I find it?